# Laravel: Show products of all subcategories

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a main category and quite a few sub-categories within that main category. When I enter the main category, I want to list all products of all sub-categories that belong to the main category.

**What i do**

**Model**

```
class Category extends Model
{
   public function children()
   {
     return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
   }

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_category', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
class FrontedController extends EcommerceController
{
   public function index()
   {
      $categories = Category::where('parent_id', 1)->where('id', '<>', 1)->get();
     
      return view('ecommerce::fronted.pages.category',['categories' => $categories,                     
                ]);
   }
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to recursively enter all subcategories. My code only displays products for the current category.

Anyone know solution?
Thanks!

Comment: You know to preload your relations using `->with([relation1, relation2])` ?
Then, you can easily access this on your view-script

Comment: if you want to show products, why are you loading the categories? show you product model

Comment: @krisgjika `$category->products`

Comment: @Paladin `with` only access to relation but no recusive to join in another and another children products.

Comment: `Category::with(['children.products'])->get()`

Comment: but yeah if you mean to get very nested categories, you need a better structure or a package that helps with this

Answer (score 1):

if you use Mysql 8, can use this packge:

[staudenmeir/laravel-adjacency-list](https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-adjacency-list)

no need any change in your structure

or other version :

[lazychaser/laravel-nestedset](https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset)

need add 2 column _lft,_rgt to your table